# jQuery Isotope Glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

My Isotope somehow does strange things, when it loads it zooms like crazy and when you filter, the images zoom and scale. It only happens once but it looks super strange. I already tried to place the jQuery at first before all the other code and I also tried to disable the CSS animations for the hover but none of these worked out.

My jQuery is:

```
// init Isotope
  var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    }
  });

  // Make filtering work
  $('.filter-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
  });

  // layout Isotope after each image loads
  $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $grid.isotope('layout');
  });

  // Highlight the active filter
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );

  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $(this).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

and a live demo can be found here:
http://dominikwierl.com/develop/v+v/projects

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed.

I've found the answer with some more searching. It's called Isotope Shaking and it can happen when there are too many animations on one object.

See: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/faq.html#items-jump-after-transitioning-position